# sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: perl

I am trying to run an executable perl file that copies a directory to another location and then removes every file in that new location except for those ending with .faa and .tsv. Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $folder = $ARGV[0];

system ("cp -r ~/directoryA/$folder/ ~/directoryB/");
chdir "~/directoryB/$folder";

# Remove everything except for .faa and .tsv files
system ("rm !\(*.faa|*.tsv\)");
```

Regardless of whether or not I escape the parenthesis, I get the error:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

and it didn't remove any files. The location of the perl file is ~/bin, and I'd like to avoid changing the #!/usr/bin/perl line since several computers will be using this script.
This is a little beyond my knowledge, as I only know basic scripting, but does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: To run, I type:
    perlfile.pl folder

perfile.pl is in a bin folder I made.

Comment: The Perl code itself is syntactically correct. The syntax error message is from the shell invoked by the second `system` call. The string being passed to the shell as a command is `"rm !(*.faa|*.tsv)"`. What did you expect the shell to do with that? The `rm` command doesn't recognize `!` or parentheses as special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complaining about this line:

```
system ("rm !\(*.faa|*.tsv\)");
```

as even if you get the quoting of the shell metacharacters right, is pretty obtuse and does not, I believe, erase all files that don't end in `.faa` or `.tsv`.

Perl is up to the latter task.

```
unlink grep { -f $_ && !/[.]faa$/ && !/[.]tsv$/ } glob("*")
```

is one of several ways.

Answer (score 2):

This entire program is much simpler without the use of shell commands

I would write this, which copies only the wanted file types in the first place. I assume there are no nested directories to be copied

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Copy 'copy';

my ($folder) = @ARGV;

while ( my $file = glob "~/directoryA/$folder/*.{faa,tsv}" ) {
    copy $file, '~/directoryB';
}
```